# For Ajax query, common function for success query, exists?

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function doWorkForJobCreate() {
    $.ajax({ url: '<%:ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteRoot"]%>/Job/JobCreate',
        success: function (data, status, req) {
            if (!processFKErrorHeader(req.getResponseHeader("fkerror"))) return;
            $("#fktabsCreate").html(data);

        }
    })
}
```

and an error processing function:

```
   function processFKErrorHeader(fkerror){
   // alert to user
   // refresh the page
   }
```

I wonder if there is a way to automatically call this function for any Ajax query succes function?

This way, I don't have to insert the error processor into every Ajax success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it takes sometime to figure out but here is the solution:

in source of jquery-1.4.2.js, add "my code":

```
function success() {

 if ( !processFKErrorHeader(xhr.getResponseHeader("fkerror")) ) //mycode
  return; //mycode

 // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
 if ( s.success ) {
  s.success.call( callbackContext, data, status, xhr );
 }

 // Fire the global callback
 if ( s.global ) {
  trigger( "ajaxSuccess", [xhr, s] );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`ajaxSuccess` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), which is broadcast to all elements.

For example:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global success handler using [`.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess) but you cannot prevent executing the other ones.

The handler gets the `settings` object which was used to set up the Ajax request. *Maybe* you can override the `success` handler there (not tested):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if (!processFKErrorHeader(req.getResponseHeader("fkerror"))) {
        settings.success = function() {};
    }
});
```

**Update:** Problem here is that I don't know whether there is an guaranteed order in which the handlers are executed.